# How do I check to see if an remote API is available when using ASP.Net Core and HttpClient

Tags: c#, http, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am working on an ASP.Net Core API that calls a 3rd party API using an HttpClient GetAsync method. If the 3rd party API is off line, the call times out but in the response that is returned, I do not see any info related to not being able to connect. The response object's StatusCode and ResponsePhrase properties say "Not Found", which is a bit misleading. Is there a way for me to know if the 3rd party API is actually running?

For example, listed below is my code for making a cal to the 3rd party API;

```
    public async Task<SAPIAddAlertSubscriberResponse> AddAlertSubscriberAsync(SAPIAddAlertSubscriberRequest a_request, CancellationToken a_cancellationToken)
    {
        try
        {
            SAPIAddAlertSubscriberResponse sapiResponse = new SAPIAddAlertSubscriberResponse();

            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                var policy = SetRetryPolicy();
                HttpResponseMessage response = null;
                var uri = $@"{m_appSettings.Value.SAPIUrl88}SAPIAddAlertSubscriber";
                string jsonInString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(a_request);
                SetHttpClientHeader(client);
                await policy.ExecuteAsync(async token =>
                {
                    response = await client.PostAsync(uri, new StringContent(jsonInString, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
                }, a_cancellationToken);

                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    result = TrimWBResponse(result, "SAPIAddAlertSubscriber");
                    sapiResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SAPIAddAlertSubscriberResponse>(result);
                }
                else
                {
                    sapiResponse.queue.Add(SetSapiError(response, uri, $"add an AlertSubscriber for CarrierLoginId {a_request.CarrierLoginPrimaryID}"));
                }
            }
            return sapiResponse;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            m_logger.LogError(1, ex, "An exception has occurred in the AddAlertSubscriberAsync method call.");
            return null;
        }
    }
```

When I make the call at a time that the 3rd party API is down, the call to the 3rd party API holds until the timeout is reached and then returns response.IsSuccessStatusCode = false. But when I examine the values in the response object's StatusCode and ResponsePhrase properties, they both just say "Not Found".

Is there a way for me to return more information that could indicate that the reason was that the API was not available?

EDIT: Added code for SetRetryPolicy

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a retry policy for a Polly instance.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>The Polly.Retry.RetryPolicy object</returns>
    /// <remarks>
    /// Supports implementation of a Polly (https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly) transient exception handler to apply exponential backoff solution for timeout errors.
    /// If a timeout transient error occurs, the call will retry after an exponentially increasing time period (starting at 1/10 second) , up to the 
    /// RetryAttempts value in the settings database 
    /// <remarks>
    private Polly.Retry.RetryPolicy SetRetryPolicy()
    {
        int retries = 0;
        var policy = Policy.Handle<Exception>()
            .WaitAndRetryAsync((int)m_appSettings.Value.SAPIRetryAttempts, attempts => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.1 * Math.Pow(2, attempts)),
            (exception, calculateWaitDuration) =>
            {
                m_logger.LogError(1, exception, "A transient exception has occurred{NewLine} ... automatically delaying for [{WaitDuration}] ms. This is retry [{Retries}].", Environment.NewLine, calculateWaitDuration, retries);
                retries++;
            });
        return policy;
    }
```

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Comment: Check the content of the response (if content length > 0) and see if any useful information was returned in the body of the response.

Comment: What's happening in `SetRetryPolicy`? When I try to use `HttpClient` to connect to a host that can't be reached, it throws an `HttpRequestException`.

Comment: @Nate Barbettini  - I added the SetRetryPolicy method code to my post for your review.